# CSS Selectors, HTML Markup, What am I missing?

Tags: html, css

I'm attempting to use a fancy JSslider, with a project I'm working on for school and I can't seem to understand why I can't get it working. It should be simple...

```
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Merienda One' rel='stylesheet'          type='text/css'>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.4.2.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="coin-slider.min.js"></script>

<div id="wTurkey">

     <h1> The Wild Turkey</h1>

    <div class="coin-slider">

    <a href="" target="_blank">

        <img src='images/cotside.jpg'>

        <span>
          <p>The Wild Turkey</p>
             Some text here
        </span>
</a>
```

At the very end of my body tag I have the following

```
  <script type="text/javascript">

  $(document).ready(function() {

    $('#coin-slider').coinslider({hoverPause: false });

    });
    </script>
  </body>
```

Here's the original site. http://workshop.rs/2010/04/coin-slider-image-slider-with-unique-effects/  I'm just basicly looking for a second set of eyes to tell me what's wrong.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is with your jQuery selector:

```
$('#coin-slider')
```

should be

```
$('.coin-slider')
```

The 'dot' denotes a css class rather than an ID (which is denoted by the # symbol)